# Empty string returned in Google Reverse geocoding webservice JSON

Tags: php, google-maps

I have tried to use Reverse geocoding Webservice in PHP.Response JSON returns Empty response only.

```
$json_string2='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=11.49813514,77.24331624&sensor=false';
$obj2=json_decode($json_string2);
$addr2=$obj2->formatted_address;
echo $addr2; //**line 1**
```

here **line 1** prints empty....What is the problem in the coding....

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you did not get the file before decode to JSON and you also called with the wrong format.

```
$json_string2 = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=11.49813514,77.24331624&sensor=false');
$obj2 = json_decode($json_string2);
$addr2 = $obj2->results[0]->formatted_address;
echo $addr2; //**line 1**
```

you could try to print this object before you call its format.

```
print_r($obj2);
```